# Laravel routes not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have just created UserController and added a route in the routes.php file:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

When I visit laravel.dev/users I expected to see the user index view, but instead I get a 404 error: The requested URL /users was not found on this server.

Here is the output when running: `php artisan routes`

```
+--------+------------------------+---------------+------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                    | Name          | Action                 | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+------------------------+---------------+------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET users              | users.index   | UserController@index   |                |               |
|        | GET users/create       | users.create  | UserController@create  |                |               |
|        | POST users             | users.store   | UserController@store   |                |               |
|        | GET users/{users}      | users.show    | UserController@show    |                |               |
|        | GET users/{users}/edit | users.edit    | UserController@edit    |                |               |
|        | PUT users/{users}      | users.update  | UserController@update  |                |               |
|        | PATCH users/{users}    |               | UserController@update  |                |               |
|        | DELETE users/{users}   | users.destroy | UserController@destroy |                |               |
|        | GET /                  |               | Closure                |                |               |
+--------+------------------------+---------------+------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Run **php artisan routes** and see what has been generated. Also, how did you setup you virtual host ?

Comment: updated the original question.

Comment: If you don't mind, it may be useful to include a little more information in the original post, such as the contents of the User Controller, routes.php file, User Model, etc.

Comment: Confirm that htaccess is a) enabled and b) working.

Answer (score 0):

You still need a matching method in the User controller for that route (matches the "action"), if you don't have one:

```
public function index() {
  return "Hello world!";
}
```

Comment: I know, it is defined in the UserController.php file.

Comment: @Severin index() or getIndex()?

Comment: public function index()
 {
  $users = User::all();

  return View::make('users.index')
   ->with('users', $users);
 }

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be some other routes.php file from where your application is running. Can you check it in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `UserController` is error free,

1) Make sure that the `url` property is configured correctly in `app/config/app.php`

2) Check whether your `.htaccess` file is working correctly.

3) Make a `composer dump-autoload --optimize`