# Laravel Routing Root dosn't work in my server

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

my laravel redirection isn't working on my server. but work locally.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('home', substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give view('home'); or controller@action instead of redirect

Comment: Yes I have test with return view ('home') but again work loccaly but dosn't working in my server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996354/laravel-routes-not-working-as-expected